# equivalent to global "before_filter" in Yesod

Tags: authentication, haskell, yesod

I have been attempting to play with Yesod, and I have run into a very simple problem that I can not seem to find a solution to.

Say I want to have a global function, that runs on every request irrelevantly of route or handler (for example an authentication function). Say I want something like

```
   uid <- requireAuthId
```

to run before every handler function and return control to the handler function when a uid is provided / if it already exists

Where would I slot this in? What is the 'Yesod Way' of doing before filters?

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, there's a [chapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194322/equivalent-to-global-before-filter-in-yesod) in Yesod book on authentication and authorisation which explains the scenario you described.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to modify your Yesod instance for your foundation type. Assuming your foundation type is called App, you can do the following to force authorization before any other handlers are called.

```
instance Yesod App where --the following lines are somewhere within this block.
    isAuthorized (AuthR LoginR) _ = return Authorized     -- You don't want to accidentally lose access to the login page!
    isAuthorized _ _ = do
        mauth <- maybeAuth
        case mauth of
             Just _ -> return Authorized
             Nothing -> return $ Unauthorized "You must login first."
```

Obviously, edit this to suit your needs, but it should give you an idea of how to do this.